# Error while adding an Image composable function in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following the android development course on developer.android.com and wile adding the above composable function I am getting the following error:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

Image(ImageBitmap, String?, Modifier = ..., Alignment = ..., ContentScale = ..., Float = ..., ColorFilter? = ..., FilterQuality = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation
Image(Painter, String?, Modifier = ..., Alignment = ..., ContentScale = ..., Float = ..., ColorFilter? = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation
Image(ImageVector, String?, Modifier = ..., Alignment = ..., ContentScale = ..., Float = ..., ColorFilter? = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation

According to the course tutorial the error should resolve after including the following import:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
```

This is the the code where i am using the imahge composable:

```
@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
        Image(
            painter = image
        )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Image` function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#Image(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter)) has **two** required parameters, not just one:

```
@Composable
fun Image(
    painter: Painter,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    alpha: Float = DefaultAlpha,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter? = null
): Unit
```

So in addition to setting the `painter`, you also must provide a `contentDescription` - that's the string that users with impaired vision will have read to them, since they cannot see what `painter` you have set:

```
@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    // Make a String resource in res/values/strings.xml
    val contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.androidparty)
    Image(
        painter = image
      )
}
```